# Updating Recycler View With Real Time Data

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java, rx-android, android-databinding

I have a list of objects that I am updating in real time (once per second). I have designed my app to use an MVVM architecture and the Android DataBinding Library

I have bound the view model to the view and everything updates fine each time I reload the activity but is there anyway to notify the view model that the model data has been updated and have the view updated accordingly in real time?

I have tried implementing the BaseObservable interface and also ObservableFields but I still get the same result.

Possibly some RxJava techniques I could use although I am unfamiliar with RxJava so any pointers to examples solving a similar problem would be helpful

Thanks

Comment: see [paging](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging.html) library, pay attention to `LivePagedListProvider`, `PagedListAdapter`  and `DataSource` (`TiledDataSource` / `KeyedDataSource`)

Comment: @pskink thanks for the suggestion, problem is that the paging library is part of the new architecture components library and I don't want to use that in my app yet as it is still in the alpha stage

Comment: Tough job to implement yourself, check this: https://mag.n26.com/reactive-clean-architecture-with-android-architecture-components-685a6682e0ca

Answer (score 0):

To get the view to update based on ViewModel change, you just need to call `notifyChange` (if you have implemented BaseObservable) or `notifyPropertyChange`.  To get the ViewModel to know that the model has updated, you could use RxJava or implement your own `onModelChanged` interface.

If you are using a ContentProvider (and CursorLoader, for example), contentProviders can also call
`getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null)`
to notify that the model has changed (which should result in onLoadFinished() being called again in the ViewModel.